# Can an UA Monk Kensei use a kensei weapon and get the +2 AC bonus if they have Extra Attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, playtesting, unearthed-arcana

Looking at the kensei ability Path of the Kensei ([Unearthed Arcana: Monk](http://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/M_2016_UAMonk1_12_12WKWT.pdf)):

> If you make an unarmed strike as part of the Attack action on your turn and are holding a kensei weapon, you can use that weapon to defend yourself. You gain a +2 bonus to AC until the start of your next turn while you are not incapacitated and the weapon is in your hand.

**Does this mean a kensei with the Extra Attack ability can take an Attack action, attack once with a kensei weapon and then once unarmed and gain the +2 AC bonus for holding a kensei weapon?**

Or have I missed something?

(I am stating that the Kensei is playtest material and not official 5e rules so that does not need to be a part of any answer)

(Just a note to say the rules mean the monk *can't* make a bonus unarmed attack because they are holding a non-monk weapon (even though it is a kensei weapon), but they *can* flurry of blows as that just requires an Attack option and has no weapon limitations)

Answer (score 7):

Crawford and Mearls have commented that the UA Monk has some odd things in it with regard to the Kensei weapons.  So, expect this to change when if/when they start considering it for inclusion.  UA material hasn't been looked at for purposes like multiclassing; but for now:

> If you make an unarmed strike **as part** of the Attack action

Means, yes, if one of your attacks in your attack action is an unarmed strike, regardless of what the other was, you gain +2 to AC if you holding a Kensei weapon.